# custom input text inside reactive form without ngModel

Tags: angular, textinput, angular-reactive-forms, two-way-binding

**my custom text input :**

```
import { Component, Inject, Injector, Input, Optional, ViewChild, Output, 
EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValueAccessorBase } from '../base-elements/value-accessor';

@Component({
selector: 'sm-input',
templateUrl: './sm-input.component.html',
providers: [{
provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
useExisting: SmInputComponent,
multi: true,
  }],
     styleUrls: ['./sm-input.component.scss'],
  })
 export class SmInputComponent extends ValueAccessorBase<string> {
 constructor(injector: Injector) {
 super(injector);
 } 
}
```

**sm-input html:**
(i removed what not was necessary)

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="label">
    <label>
       {{label}} 
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input  
      type="text" 
      pInputText
      [(ngModel)]="value"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

**my form:**

```
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'sm-input-example-in-reactive-from',
  templateUrl: './sm-input-example-in-reactive-from.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sm-input-example-in-reactive-from.component.scss']
})
export class SmInputExampleInReactiveFromComponent {

  public firstName: string = "Bob";
  myReactiveForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private http: Http) {
    this.myReactiveForm = fb.group ({
      myField: [this.firstName, [Validators.required]],
    });
  }
  onSubmit(value) {
    console.log(`Submit: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
  }
}
```

**html form**

```
<p-panel header="Reactive Form">
  <form action="" [formGroup]="myReactiveForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myReactiveForm.value)">
    <div class="ui-grid-row">
      <sm-input
        label="First Name"
        formControlName="myField">
      </sm-input> 
  </div>
  <div class="ui-grid-row">
      <div class="ui-g-2 ui-g-offset-5">
          <button type="Submit" class="" pButton [disabled]="!myReactiveForm.valid">Submit</button>
        </div> 
  </div>
</form>
</p-
```

in sm-input html i used in [(ngModel)]="value".

**it's working.** but i don't want to use in 
[(ngMode)]="value"

because reactive form not need to work with ngMode.
i read this post 
[Two way binding in reactive forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458739/two-way-binding-in-reactive-forms)

and its not a good idea to mix between driven form and reactive form.

angular doc: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

**"...For this reason, the ngModel directive is not part of the ReactiveFormsModule".**

what should i do?

thank you.

Comment: What's the problem you have? If you don't want to use ngModel then don't use it.

Comment: you seem to know about data binding, you use it in the example, so just use it once again on the inputs value or where ever you need it ...

Comment: "so just use it once again on the inputs value or where ever you need it".    i need to bind the formControler (firstName) to my custom component. in host component(form) i created instance of my custom component (sm-input) with formControlName bind to firstName in form.ts.  how can i bind the formControler (firstName) to my custom input component without [(ngModel)].

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `.setValue()` method. As the name suggests, it allows you to programatically set the value of your reactive form control.

Here is a link to the relevant section in Angular's guides: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#populate-the-form-model-with-setvalue-and-patchvalue

And here is a link to the method in the API: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue

---

**First Approach (Use a `BehaviorSubject` to represent the current input value on your custom component)**
To get the value of your custom input component, you could make a stream on your custom text input which represents it's value over time.

```
inputValue$ = new BehaviorSubject('');
```

And listen to the `input` event on that input field.

```
<input (input)="onInputChange($event)">
```

Then update your `inputValue$` stream with the most recent value in your input.

```
onInputChange(mostRecentInputValue: string) {
  this.inputValue$.next(mostRecentInputValue);
}
```

Now you have a stream on your custom input that you can subscribe to in the parent.

Finally, in your form component you can use the `@ViewChild` decorator to get ahold of your custom input component and thereby access it's public properties (which include the `inputValue$`:

```
@ViewChild('sm-input') myCustomInput: SmInputComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myCustomInput.inputValue$.subscribe(mostRecentInput => {
     this.myReactiveForm.get('myField').setValue(mostRecentInput);
  }
}
```

---

**Second Approach (Use `@Output`)**

On your custom input:

```
<input (input)="onInputChange($event)">
```

Then use an `EventEmitter` with `@Output` decorator to send that change to the parent;

```
@Output inputChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

onInputChange(mostRecentInputValue: string) {
  this.inputChange.emit(mostRecentInputValue);
}
```

Then in your parent html:

```
<sm-input (inputChange)="onSmInputChange($event)">
```

And your component:

```
onSmInputChange(recentValue: string) {
  this.myReactiveForm.get('myField').setValue(recentValue);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i know about 'setValue' and 'patchValue'. but it's still not the solution.  how can i bind the 'formControl' (firstName) from my fromGroup to custom input text component (sm-input).

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

**solved,
thanks all!**

Custom text:

```
import { Component, Inject, Injector, Input, Optional, ViewChild, Output, 
EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValueAccessorBase } from '../base-elements/value-accessor';

@Component({
selector: 'sm-input',
templateUrl: './sm-input.component.html',
providers: [{
provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
useExisting: SmInputComponent,
multi: true,
  }],
     styleUrls: ['./sm-input.component.scss'],
  })
 export class SmInputComponent extends ValueAccessorBase<string> {
 constructor(injector: Injector) {
 super(injector);
 } 

  doChange($event) {
   this.value = $event.target.value;
  }
}
```

**sm-input html:**

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="label">
    <label>
       {{label}} 
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input  
      type="text" 
      [value]"innerValue"
      (change)="doChange($event)"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

(innerValue defined in ValueAccessorBase)

thanks all!