# How can I bind a form to a model in Angular 6 using reactive forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Prior to angular 6, I was using `[(ngModel)]` to directly bind my form field to the model. This is now deprecated (can't use with reactive forms) and I am not sure how to update my model with the form values. I could use `form.getRawValue()` but this would require me to replace my current model with the new rawValue - this is not favourable since my main model is larger and has more fields than the local form model.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could assign each column from form to your object. Is it convinient?

Comment: there is no `ngModel` deprecation mentioned in angular change log (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600-2018-05-03) or at angular.io (https://angular.io/guide/forms#two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel)

Comment: @Andriy Sorry, I meant to say I get a warning if I use ngModel with reactive forms.

Comment: @MaximKasyanov Thanks, I am currently considering doing this but looking for other options as well.

Comment: please post (if you can) reactive form code using ngModel which stopped working since ng6

Comment: Did you even read Angular's tutorial **explicilty explaining** how to do this ?

Comment: @Andriy https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Don't use `[(ngModel)]`! Reactive forms are much nicer. They make manual `ngModel` bindings obsolete, and they have some pretty sweet built-in features only a couple of which I'm going to cover in this answer.

## Binding to the form

If you're binding to a form control such as a text input, use this template syntax:

```html
<ng-container [formGroup]="this.myFormGroup">
    <input type="text" formControlName="field1">
    <input type="text" formControlName="field2">
    <ng-container formGroupName="subgroupName">
        <input type="text" formControlName="subfield2">
    </ng-container>
    <input type="text" formControlName="myRequiredField">
</ng-container>
```

*(`field1`, `field2`, `subgroupName`, `subfield2`, and `myRequiredField` are all arbitrary control and control group names that correspond to parts of your form, see below when creating the `FormGroup` object.)*

> **Note on [`<ng-container>`](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-container)**: You can, of course, also use any other tag in place of `<ng-container>` if that makes more semantic sense. E.g. `<form [formGroup]="this.myFormGroup">`. I used `<ng-container>` here because it doesn't create an extra HTML element when rendered; `<ng-container><div /></ng-container>` appears in the DOM tree as just a `<div/>`. Great if you use CSS that depends on the tags having a certain structure.

Read-only data bindings to the model of the `FormGroup` are accessed a little differently in your template:

```html
{{ this.myFormGroup.get('field1').value }}
{{ this.myFormGroup.get('subgroupName.subfield2').value }}
<!-- Hint: use an array if you have field names that contain "." -->
{{ this.myFormGroup.get(['subgroupName', 'subfield2']).value }}
```

## Creating the `FormGroup`

In your component class, in `constructor()` (this should be before the template renders), use the following syntax to build a form group to talk to this form:

```typescript
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

...
    public readonly myFormGroup: FormGroup;
...
    constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.myFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
            field1: [],
            field2: [],
            subgroupName: this.formBuilder.group({
                subfield2: [],
            }),
            myRequiredField: ['', Validators.required],
        });
        this.retrieveData();
    }
```

## Filling your form with data

If your component needs to retrieve data from a service as it loads, you must make sure it starts the transfer after the form has been built, then use `patchValue()` to put the data from your object into the `FormGroup`:

```typescript
    private retrieveData(): void {
        this.dataService.getData()
            .subscribe((res: SomeDataStructure) => {
                // Assuming res has a structure matching the template structure
                // above, e.g.:
                // res = {
                //     field1: "some-string",
                //     field2: "other-string",
                //     subgroupName: {
                //         subfield2: "another-string"
                //     },
                // }
                // Values in res that don't line up to the form structure
                // are discarded. You can also pass in your own object you
                // construct ad-hoc.
                this.myFormGroup.patchValue(res);
            });
    }
```

## Getting data out of the form

Now, say your user clicks submit and now you need to get the data back out of your form and `POST` it back to your API thru a service. Just use `getRawValue`:

```typescript
public onClickSubmit(): void {
    if (this.myFormGroup.invalid) {
        // stop here if it's invalid
        alert('Invalid input');
        return;
    }
    this.myDataService.submitUpdate(this.myFormGroup.getRawValue())
        .subscribe((): void => {
            alert('Saved!');
        });
}
```

All these techniques eliminate the need for any `[(ngModel)]` bindings, since the form maintains its own internal model inside the `FormGroup` object.

Comment: "this.myFormGroup.patchValue(res);" this was the key for me, the documentation sucks - I was trying to figure out how to load an Edit form from an object received from a service call (I'm new to Angular) - thanks!

Comment: Where is the reactive form getting bound to a Model object?

Comment: It's done thru the `[formGroup]="this.myFormGroup"` directive. This binds it to the model stored in the `FormGroup` object, which you can later get at by calling `this.myFormGroup.getRawValue`, etc.

Comment: very helpful to see specific examples. Hard to find !

Comment: This answer helped me to understand form builder better. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 28):

As explained more fully in the [Angular Documentation](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html), with reactive forms, you do not bind the form directly to **your** model. Rather, you use a FormBuilder to build a FormGroup object (essentially, "the form") that will maintain it's own model.
During construction, you have the opportunity to set initial values in the form, which you would usually do from **your** model.

You then bind form controls in your template to the form's model.
User interaction with the form controls updates the form's model.

When you are ready to do something with the form data (e.g. "submit" the form),
you can get the values from the form fields by using either the FormGroup's value property or it's getRawValue() method - these two behave differently, see the documentation for details.

Once you get the values from the form, if you wish, you can update **your** model with the values from the form.

Comment: > `You then bind form controls in your template to the form's model. User interaction with the form controls updates the form's model.`
Are you suggesting to use `[(ngModel)]` within the template?

Comment: No. You create a FormGroup in the component, and bind the HTML inputs to that with the attribute 'formControlName'.  Again, see the documentation, e.g.https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName

Comment: How do you bind reactive form to model's id? using hidden form control?

Comment: You don't. That's kind of the point. The form has it's own model. It's not bound to yours. You can get the 'value' property of the form, and do what you want with it, including updating your model, but your model is explicitly NOT bound to the form.

Comment: Was looking for this info. Thanks.

Comment: You can keep saying see the doc's but the doc's don't show you how to do this. They don't show you how to BIND your reactive form to a Model object.  They show how to log to the console some data but couldn't find any example for how to bind one way and two way to the backing model. I started with the link from the warning message then yours regarding with were a similar story. No actually explanation or examples of BINDING to a MODEL.  That is what ngModel does... it binds with reactive forms I have form controls with data but no data getting to a model.

Comment: This is the first clear explanation of how this all fits together that I have found, after checking out many many blog posts.

Comment: @RodneyS.Foley I suggest you re-read this response. You'll then understand that Reactive Forms are **not** designed to behave the same way as Template Drive Forms. What `ngModel` does do not _exists_ with Reactive Forms. There is no "binding to my (business) model".
**You** are in charge of filling your business model with the values from the form model. If you don't like that, then use a Template Driven form.

Answer (score 4):

You can subscribe to changes in your form group and use it to update your model. But this is not safety. Because you must ensure that your form fields match the model fields or add verification that the fields in the model exist.

```
bindModelToForm(model: any, form: FormGroup) {
    const keys = Object.keys(form.controls);
    keys.forEach(key => {
        form.controls[key].valueChanges.subscribe(
            (newValue) => {
                model[key] = newValue;
            }
        )
    });
}
```

Full code of my service: 
*referenceFields* - means if you have complex fields like `student: { name, group }` where *group* is a referenced model, and you need to be able to get only id from this model:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FormService {

    constructor() {
    }

    bindModelToForm(model: any, form: FormGroup, referenceFields: string[] = []) {
        if (!this.checkFieldsMatching(model, form)) {
            throw new Error('FormService -> bindModelToForm: Model and Form fields is not matching');
        }
        this.initForm(model, form);
        const formKeys = Object.keys(form.controls);
        formKeys.forEach(key => {
            if (referenceFields.includes(key)) {
                form.controls[key].valueChanges.subscribe(
                    (newValue) => {
                        model[key] = newValue.id;
                    }
                )
            } else {
                form.controls[key].valueChanges.subscribe(
                    (newValue) => {
                        model[key] = newValue;
                    }
                )
            }
        });
    }

    private initForm(model: any, form: FormGroup) {
        const keys = Object.keys(form.controls);
        keys.forEach(key => {
            form.controls[key].setValue(model[key]);
        });
    }

    private checkFieldsMatching(model: any, form: FormGroup): boolean {
        const formKeys = Object.keys(form.controls);
        const modelKeys = Object.keys(model);
        formKeys.forEach(formKey => {
            if (!modelKeys.includes(formKey)) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```