# How to dynamically check a radio button with Angular Reactive Forms?

Tags: angular, forms

quick question.
I am getting data from the database and I want to show to data to the user, using Reactive Forms (the user doesn't change anything, that's just the UI chosen to show the data)
I have some boolean values : 0 - no, 1-yes . I want to show those values in corresponding radio buttons (1 button will mean yes, 1 button will mean no, and the correct one will be checked)
How do I dynamically add the "checked" property to the radio button groups?
Code added below. (This doesn't work, obviously)
Thanks!

```
   <div class="d-flex">
    <label
      ><input
        type="radio"
        formControlName="fcw"
        class="ml-2"
        value="1"
        [checked]="vehicleData.fcw == 1 ? true : false"
      />כן
    </label>

    <label class="mr-5"
      ><input
        type="radio"
        formControlName="fcw"
        value="0"
        class="ml-2"
        [checked]="vehicleData?.fcw == 0 ? true : false"
      />לא</label
    >
  </div>
```

Comment: NOT use [checked] if you has a FormControl, is the value of formControl who indicate the input the value

Comment: @Or Shoham The method which works for me is to use [(ngModel)]  = "vehicleData.fcw".

Comment: @Toby thanks. I tried that but got the following error:
ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.  Try using
      formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.
I guess that means we cant use ngModel with formGroup and Reactive forms

Comment: @OrShoham Ah ok you have a FormGroup too. I think ngModel was deprecated, but it's hard to keep up with Angular sometimes. It seems like the current way to set form values in ReactiveForms with a FormGroup is to use setValue or patchValue  on the form group itself from your component, rather than binding to the model in the UI. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342775/how-can-i-bind-a-form-to-a-model-in-angular-6-using-reactive-forms  So would that work for you?

Comment: Ok so basically the solution was to use [value] ="1" and [value]="0" for both radio buttons, and that worked perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a boolean variable and set it to true or false depending if you want to check or uncheck the buttons.In the code you can do like thie:

```
   <div class="d-flex">
<label
  ><input
    type="radio"
    formControlName="fcw"
    class="ml-2"
    value="1"
    [checked]="{{yourVariable}}"
  />כן
</label>

<label class="mr-5"
  ><input
    type="radio"
    formControlName="fcw"
    value="0"
    class="ml-2"
    [checked]="{{yourVariable}}"
  />לא</label
>
```

By doing this in the component you should have a variable `yourVariable` and change it's value.

Comment: I thought about something like that but what difference does that make? 0 and 1 are considered booleans themselves arent they? Also, before I switched the form to a Reactive Form, that logic that I posted above worked just fine..

Comment: if the formControl get the value "0", the input type="radio" with the value 0 is checked. NOT use [checked] in a formControl, Angular "checked it" for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Renderer2 setAttribute /setProperty method
and add a @viewchildren decorator over the radiobuttons and get hold of the radio buttons