# Difference between *ngFor vs @for in Angular 17

Tags: angular, angular17

Been trying to upgrade and migrate some of my angular projects into Angular 17. Also still learning the standalone component as part of the major upgrade of the said version.

One thing I noticed is the documentation is they are using now the `@for` eg.

```
@for (car of cars; track car) {
   <option [value]="car.value">{{car.viewValue}}</option>
}
```

instead of `*ngFor`

```
<option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car.value">{{car.viewValue}}</option>
```

To be honest, I'm still liking the `*ngFor`.

Any difference between these two or is **`@for` is the new `*ngFor`?** If that so, any particular reason are they doing that? `*ngFor` is much simpler and can be one liner.

Comment: Check out official docs: https://angular.io/guide/control_flow#comparing-built-in-control-flow-to-ngif-ngswitch-and-ngfor

Comment: maybe this question and answer gave you a better overview:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77534086/angular-v17-prospects-of-if-vs-ngif-will-ngif-be-deprecated-in-the-future/78008634#78008634

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@for` block is part of the new [control flow syntax](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow) introduced in Angular 17.0

The control flow blocks (`@if`, `@for`, `@switch`) are here to replace the 3 structural directives `ngIf`, `ngFor` and `ngSwitch`.

In the case of the `@for` block, feature wise they serve the same purpse with a few advantages :

- No need to import the directive in standalone components
- Generate a bit less code in the final bundle
- enable better DX for `track` by passing a key directly.
- Make devs more concious about the `track` functionality by making it required.
- Nice DX for empty for-loops with the `@empty` block

Answer (score 0):

The **@for** block makes it easier to loop through items in a collection and manage them efficiently.

Unlike NgFor, which needs a *trackBy* function to identify each item uniquely, **@for** just needs a simple tracking expression.

If the collection is empty, you can use the **@empty** block to display something specific.

Also, **@for** automatically figures out the least amount of changes needed to update the list on the screen, making it more efficient than NgFor, which allowed for custom ways to track changes but @for doesn't support that.