Old control flow is supported in latest angular version 18?
This is the latest control flow in angular 18.
@if(condition) {
   <button>If Condition</button>
} 
@else {
   <button>Else Condition</button>
}

And This is the old way.
<ng-container *ngIf="state1; else default">State 1 selected</ng-container>

<ng-template #default> No state is selected. </ng-template>

Does this old way is still valid in angular 18 or not?

this question already exists and has a better response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78015711/15262752

Yes, you can use the old method, it's a matter of preference.
The difference is that, we can use @if, @for directly without any imports.
But when doing *ngIf or *ngFor you need to import the CommonModule, or the directives directly NgIf, NgFor from '@angular/core'.

New Syntax Demo - no imports!
Old Syntax Demo - needs imports
