# Why ionChange/ ngModelChange is executing from ion-checkbox where I dont call?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have one `ion-datetime` and one `ion-check-box`. If I choose a date, the checkbox should be `false`, if I click in the checkbox and the `ion-datetime` has a value that should then be empty.

https://prnt.sc/kx0ucq

```
 <form [formGroup]="registrationForm">   
    <ion-item>       
      <ion-label floating>Fecha Fin</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD-MM-YYYY" formControlName="date_end" 
                    (ngModelChange)="checkCheckEndDate()">
      </ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
 </form>
 <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Trabajo aquí actualmente</ion-label>
     <ion-checkbox (click)="addValue()" [(ngModel)]="checked"></ion-checkbox>
 </ion-item>
```

My component is `checked: boolean = false;`

**Constructor:**

```
this.registrationForm = formBuilder.group({
     date_end: ['',]
 });
```

**And these 2 :**

```
addValue(): void {
    alert("addValue"+this.checked);
    if(this.checked){
      this.registrationForm.controls['date_end'].setValue('');
    }
  }

  checkCheckEndDate(){
    alert("checkCheckEndDate");
    if(this.registrationForm.controls['date_end'])
    {
      alert("if"+this.registrationForm.controls['date_end'].value)
      this.checked=false;
      alert(this.checked);
    }else{
      alert("no"+this.registrationForm.controls['date_end'].value)
      this.checked=true;
      alert(this.checked);
    }
  }
```

My question is, why does it execute `checkCheckEndDate()` when I click in check box ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ion-datetime` element is configured to run the `checkCheckEndDate` method when its value changes, and you are changing its value within the `addValue` method, which runs when the `ion-checkbox` is clicked.  This is expected behaviour.

Note that [Angular core developers advise against mixing usage of reactive forms & `ngModel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458739/two-way-binding-in-reactive-forms#comment76512981_40459321).  Your desired behaviour could be achieved without `ngModel` by setting up an `Observable` on the two fields (using `valueChanges`).

To monitor the `date_end` field and update the `ion-checkbox` accordingly, you could write code similar to this after initialising the `FormGroup`:

```
this.registrationForm.get('date_end').valueChanges.subscribe(val => this.checked = !val);
```

With this code in place you don't need the `checkCheckEndDate` method.

Comment: I don't understand your answer completely @Alex Peters,  could you send example or write some lines here to achieve that ? if i remove FormGroup how can i validate my form ? because i have more inputs.

Comment: I've edited to add some example code, and removed the note on removing the `ion-checkbox` from the `FormGroup` (because actually, you don't include it in the `FormGroup`).