# Angular load selected dropdown value in edit mode

Tags: angular, angular-forms

HTML -

```
<select id="gender" formControlName="gender" [(ngModel)]="gender">
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Gender</option> 
            <option [value]="gender" *ngFor="let gender of genderObj">{{gender}}</option> 
</select>
```

TS -

```
genderObj = ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formDetails();
}

initForm() {
    this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
      gender: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
  }

 formDetails() {
    this.userService.getFormDetails(this.Id)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.data = res.body.data;
      });
  }
```

I want to get a prefilled/autoselected value of dropdown if the value of gender from **API** is **gender:'M'** then Male.
If value is **gender:"F"** then **Female**.
And if **empty string** then **Select gender** placeholder.
Tried with setValue and patchValue but nothing comes.

Comment: why use `ngModel` and reactive forms? see here for why
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458739/two-way-binding-in-reactive-forms#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20%5B(ngModel)%5D%20with%20Reactive%20forms.&text=This%20will%20a%20completely%20different,NgModel%20directive%20would%20be%20used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `.subscribe` block you can set the gender of the form. As we do not know the structure of your returned data, you have to implement the gender specific stuff on your own. Setting the forms value, you can do the following:

`this.form.gender.patchValue(...) <-- set the value here`